# Select option values from Flask backend to React frontend

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

I am quite new to Javascript and React framework however I am trying to create a dashboard in which the select dropdown button should display a list of hospitals which are process from data in flask backend. I have tried this with html frontend which worked but trying on react doesnt work. Here is how my react select dropdown looks line

```
function Header(){
return(
<p id="label">Select Hospital:</p>
<select labelId="label" id="select" value="20">
    <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit county hospital</option>
    <option value="{{hospitals[0]}}" selected>{{hospitals[0]}}</option>
    {% for hospital in hospitals[1:] %}
    <option value="{{hospital}}">{{hospital}}</option>
    {%endfor%}
</select>
)}
```

Here is my Flask backend :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import Flask, render_template
import dash_backend

app = Flask(__name__)

# List of Hospitals


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():

    hosp_list = dash_backend.hosp_list

    return render_template('index.html', hospitals=hosp_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

How can I be able to fetch data(list of hospitals) from this flask backend to React frontend select dropdown button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a react component to make a back-end call to an API and render the list last select dropdown. I have used a sample API in the code. You can replace it with your flask API.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  // to store all the hospitals
  const [hospitals, setHospitals] = useState([]);

  // to store selected hospital
  const [selectedHospital, setSelectedHospital] = useState('');

  // Make API call to get all hospitals on mount of the component
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setHospitals(data);
      });
  }, []);

  // Render the hospital list
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Selected Hospital: {selectedHospital}</div>
      <select onChange={e => setSelectedHospital(e.target.value)}>
        <option value="">Select Hospital</option>
        {hospitals.map(hospital => (
          <option key={hospital.id}>{hospital.name}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If my hospitals is a list like this ```['Keya hospital', 'mugr hospital', 'Dike hospital']``` How can I add  id  key and also another identify like 'name' so that to select hospitals separately?

Comment: if you dont have an id you can use the index of the array as id. if your array is just a plain array of strings then you dont have to do `{hospital.name}` you can just do `{hospital}`